# Ace editor console.log()

Tags: javascript, console, ace-editor

I am currently testing the Ace code editor(http://ace.c9.io/) and embedded into a webpage.
I am wondering if it's possible to create a output console to display console.log and output commands. Currently, I am using eval() to evaluate the code but as there is no console, the console.log command won't display. 
I want the editor to be able to output like in CodeCademy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Console is completely unrelated to ace. You need to create your own.
Which is not very hard, you need to overwrite the global for console, and write some function that stringifies objects and either adds that string to another editor or to a dom node.
You may want to have a look at other projects that have a console e.g. https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/blob/master/public/js/render/console.js

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know of any Javascript tutorials on consoles?